# Retrieving image url from webpage using IMPORTXML in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, web-scraping, xpath

I have this webpage: https://www.loupe360.com/diamond/LG464120206/img

And I am trying to retrieve the jpg url using IMPORTXML in google sheets.

example jpg link: https://nivoda-images.s3.amazonaws.com/aHR0cDovL2RuYS5kaWFtb25kdmlkLmNvbS8/aWQ9NjA0NS00LUNWRC1m/0.jpg

I have seen answers online that //img/@src is supposed to retrieve the url but this does not work on my webpage, I have experimented with many different xpath queries, but still cannot seem to retrieve any data from this webpage and I'm not sure why.

Comment: `<noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>` ... so it seems that it is not possible here https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/115664/how-to-know-if-google-sheets-importdata-importfeed-importhtml-or-importxml-fun

Answer (score 0):

if you know the image url you can do:

```
=IMAGE("https://nivoda-images.s3.amazonaws.com/aHR0cDovL2RuYS5kaWFtb25kdmlkLmNvbS8/aWQ9NjA0NS00LUNWRC1m/0.jpg")
```

[image]